# Which sites use Apache OFBiz?

Tags: ofbiz

I'm collecting some data for a presentation.

Does anyone know sites hosted on Apache Ofbiz or users of this ecommerce package outside of the list at https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/apache-ofbiz-user-list.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one site: http://wow.com

Comment: Yes it is down now, however at that time it used to be a daily deal site.

Answer (score 12):

Some examples you can find in [Apache OFBiz® wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Home):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Apache+OFBiz+User+List

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Apache+OFBiz+Service+Providers

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Apache+OFBiz+User+Stories

Answer (score 3):

Ofbiz is not dead. A rather very pessimistic view from @Jimmy.

- United Air: [www.united.com](http://www.united.com/)
- TITAN Company: [www.titan.co.in](http://www.titan.co.in/)
- Vishal Megamart: [www.myvishal.com](http://www.myvishal.com/)

These are few big houses, for example, who are using Ofbiz/derivative.

Comment: https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fwww.united.com%2fual%2fen%2fus%2f - ASP.NET
So it is not using Ofbiz at least for the site implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Truly, not many are using Ofbiz, The link which is posted above shows a list of maybe 70 websites, if you click on them you will see that most websites are DOWN.
Those who are not down, have not been updated for years.

So long story short, Ofbiz is a dead-end. 
I can strongly just warn people to specify their skills with Ofbiz.
No company actually needs this. I just googled and searched for Jobs in whole Germany for companies who are looking for people who know how to deal with Ofbiz. Results ZERO.

Comment: Actually, I cannot agree it is a dead-end. It has a great ERP model inside, so can be used as a template for development ERP system at least. Also it has alot of OOTB functionality to extend any system which lack of that.

Comment: Saying that OFBiz is a dead end is just ignoring what happens in big companies. They don't want to show off, or rather tell that they use OFBiz, but they are many to use it... Of course for a manager it's easier to say that he uses SAP, SalesForce, Oracle, IBM, you name it...